# Swagger-ui Validation issue with REST API

Tags: validation, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, swagger-codegen

I am trying to integrate Swagger in my existing application for REST APIs.
While running on localhost I am getting the expected result in Swagger UI.
But when I deploy my .war file on DAP and try to access it is not able to read the JSON from the URL.

```
{"schemaValidationMessages":[{"level":"error","message":Cant read from file..
```

I suppose this is a validator issue.
I cannot make the link public as I work for a bank and it has to be private and secure at any cost.
Alternately I tried to bypass the validator.
I have already tried setting `validatorUrl = null` in my index.html.
Also i have set `validatorUrl = null in my swagger-ui.js` file.
Both these don't seem to work.

Can any one please guide me on how can I go about doing this as this is really important and critical.

Comment: hi, if any one has any leads for this issue please let me know.